# Using Azure functions to serve dynamic HTML pages (with databound controls)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

I know how to use Azure functions to serve static HTML pages, but now I want to develop kind of a single page app using Azure functions and I'm stuck in the following scenario:

On the HTML page a want to generate and serve I need to have data bound controls (drop down, text box, etc).
Considering I have an SQL database, how can I bound those controls to data? Do I need to use a separate HTML template with some variables that I can bound them from within the function? Or do I need separate Azure function for each data source and use them as REST data sources for the HTML controls?

The dynamic scenario is pretty unclear to me so if anybody can give some hints, examples, it would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Just for clarification, are you wanting to actually serve the HTML from the Function.  Or are you hosting a javascript-base SPA that uses the Function as a backend API?

Comment: I would like to serve the full HTML from the Function, if it is possible to somehow bind controls to data. If this cannot be done, then I would settle for serving a JS based SPA and use Function as backend API

Comment: Did you find a solution?